# How return to the custom Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have Activity1, Activity2, Activity3. Activity1 - is a List of items, (Categories of dishes), when user click to the category the next Activity2 appears with dishes by category, then user click and may see details about dish. But when he click BackButton on the ActionBar button I have exception. Because Activity2 depend on the what exactly chose user on the Activity1. Lets see

```
 str = intent.getDataString(); // Here exception because of null

    if (str.equals(SALAD)) {
        //  arr = getDishByCategoryId(SALAD_KEY);
        return new CursorLoader(
                getActivity(),
                SantafeContract.DishEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                FORECAST_COLUMNS,
                SantafeContract.DishEntry.COLUMN_CAT_KEY + " = ?",
                new String[]{Long.toString(SALAD_KEY)},
                null
        );
    }
    // Users chose cold dishes
    else if (str.equals(COLD)) {
      }
```

So how I can return to the Activity2 from Activity3 where user will see all dishes of category?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: str is a NULL so it is nullPointerException,it is beacuse I came not form Activity1 but from Activity3 to Activity2